# How to toggle dark theme in Angular when I click on the switch?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, class

I am using angular and I am trying to switch between light and dark themes. The toggle switch is in my header component. Please see below

[image]

And my header component is the child component in the app component. See below also

```
// app.component.html    

    <app-header (mode)="receiveMode($event)"></app-header>

     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Therefore, I set the boolean value for the toggle theme in my header component TS file

```
// header.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit , Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() mode = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  setDark = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  onChangeToggle() {
    this.setDark = !this.setDark;
    this.mode.emit(this.setDark);
    console.log(this.setDark);
  }

}
```

I then pass that value to the parent component with the Output decorator and receive it in the app.component.ts file so that all other components can have the theme as well, (not just HomeComponent).

```
// app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  setMode = false;

  receiveMode($event) {
    this.setMode = $event;
    console.log("MODEEEE", this.setMode);
  }


  title = 'about-me';
}
```

I then receive the boolean value from the app-header in the app.component.html file

```
// app.component.html

    <app-header (mode)="receiveMode($event)"></app-header>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And I added the darkTheme class to my global stylessheet in styles.css

```
.darkTheme {
    background-color: black;
}
```

I want to know how  can use ngClass or ngStyle to set it conditionally based on the boolean value.

Comment: Just add `darkTheme` class to the document body of your overrides are in styles.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just finished implementing my version of this feature.  I’m using three sources:

- PrimeNG's showcase website (source    https://github.com/primefaces/primeng),
- Video from Primefaces    (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5VOuUdDXRsE and source at    https://github.com/yigitfindikli/primeng-dynamic-theming),
- Bootstrap watch (https://bootswatch.com/).

The general idea is to use style link in *index.html* with id of **app-theme** and not use the styles array in the *angular.json*.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DemoStyle</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link id="app-theme" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/themes/primeng.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/themes/styles.css">
</head>
<body id='body-color-theme' [data-bs-theme]='light'>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

If you are using SCSS, see the video and *angular.json*.

I’ve added a data attribute of **data-bs-theme**, that I took from Bootstrap watch.  This allows for one to do something like the following in the *styles.css*:

```
:root {
  --nsg-jumbotron-bg-color: var(--gray-100);
  [data-bs-theme="dark"] {
    --nsg-jumbotron-bg-color: var(--gray-700);
  }
}
```

Both the PrimeNG’s showcase and the video use a service as the root source for logic.  My variation of the service has a '**is dark**' boolean property and a '**switch theme**' method.  The theme service is as follows:

```
import { Inject, Injectable, Renderer2, RendererFactory2  } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
//
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ThemeService {
  //
  private _renderer: Renderer2;
  _folder: string = '/assets/themes';
  _rootTheme: string = 'lara';
  _rootColor: string = 'blue';
  //
  _isDarkTheme: boolean = false;
  get isDarkTheme() {
    return this._isDarkTheme;
  }
  //
  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT)
    private _document: Document,
    rendererFactory: RendererFactory2 ) {
      this._renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
  }
  /**
  ** Change the <link id="app-theme" rel="stylesheet" ... in the index.html
  ** to different light or dark theme.  Additionally set 'data-bs-theme' to
  ** the theme color, so one can set extra CSS values beyond the PrimeNG theme.
  ** @param isDark boolean
  */
  switchTheme(isDark: boolean) {
    const _themeLink = this._document.getElementById('app-theme') as HTMLLinkElement;
    if (_themeLink) {
      // change the <link id="app-theme" rel="stylesheet" ... 
      const _theme = isDark ? 'dark' : 'light';
      const _link = `${this._folder}/${this._rootTheme}-${_theme}-${this._rootColor}/theme.css`;
      _themeLink.href = _link;
      console.log( `Theme: ${_link}` );
      this._isDarkTheme = isDark;
      // additionally set 'data-bs-theme' to the theme color
      const _colorTheme = this._document.getElementById('body-color-theme');
      console.log ( _colorTheme );
      if( _colorTheme !== null ) {
        this._renderer.setAttribute( _colorTheme, 'data-bs-theme', _theme );
        console.log( `Theme: ${_theme}` );
      }
    }
  }
  //
}
```

I created a component to handle toggling between light and dark themes.  The HTML was taken from PrimeNG’s showcase code as follows:

```
<button type="button"
  [style]="{ 'width': '2.7rem', 'height': '2.7rem', 'border-radius': '4px' }"
  (click)="changeTheme(!isDarkMode)">
  <i class="pi " [ngClass]="{'pi-moon': isDarkMode, 'pi-sun': !isDarkMode}"></i>
</button>
```

The component's code is as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ThemeService } from './theme.service';
//
@Component({
  selector: 'app-toggle-theme',
  templateUrl: './toggle-theme.component.html',
  styleUrl: './toggle-theme.component.css'
})
export class ToggleThemeComponent {
  //
  constructor(
    private themeService: ThemeService
  ) { }
  //
  get isDarkMode() {
    return this.themeService.isDarkTheme;
  }
  //
  changeTheme(theme: boolean): number {
    return this.themeService.switchTheme(theme);
  }
  //
}
```

The above basically just calls theme service.

I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dvegds?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Ftoggle-theme%2Ftheme.service.ts).  The

```
[data-bs-theme="dark"]
```

doesn't work, because it can't find style.css.

The following change in *angular.json* fixed the above problem:

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.scss",
  "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css"
],
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it:

```
<div [ngClass]="{
  darkTheme: setMode
}">
</div>
```

You can also add additional classes and conditions in the same ngClass.

Another:

```
<div [class.darkTheme]="setMode"></div>
```

EDIT: As mentioned in my comment, I would prefer this approach:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/theme/css/dark-theme.min.css" *ngIf="setMode">
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but my components dont have access to the setMode which is in the app component. Since there is no parent-child relationship, it cannot pass through by the Input() or Output() also. Thanks for your response anyways!

Comment: @kennyman335 I only answered "I want to know how can use ngClass or ngStyle to set it conditionally based on the boolean value" which is the only question (that can be considered) in your post. Also, if you are using a theme then any child component should be oblivious to the theme change. You're better off importing a dark-theme.css that targets html elements and removing it based on your boolean value.

Comment: I'll revoke what I mentioned on my previous comment as I remember that the Angular way for styling is to avoid global styles and more on isolation, if this was any other app then I'd go for what I said earlier. What you are lacking on your application is state management. If you have let's say redux to store your application states then you can get the boolean value on when to set the dark theme on any component. Use that with the [ngClass] and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi, you are absolutely right about the state management. I managed to find the issue with why it wasnt showing the black tint. It worked after I took out the HTML and Body tags of the home component. I figured it had to do with something with the html and body tags being there after discovering the other components which didnt have the tags were able to toggle between light and dark. Now I am just figuring out how to put state managemnt because the boolean sets back to false after switching tabs, which sets the boolean back to default. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-prkazr I've created for this question.

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
export class AppComponent {
  setMode = false;

  receiveMode($event) {
    this.setMode = $event;
    console.log("MODEEEE", this.setMode);
  }
}
```

you need `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` in your app.component decoration to enable using the parent's styles in it's children components see https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation, this is because `::ng-deep` is deprecated see https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep for more info.

app.component.html

```
<div id="main-container" [ngClass]="[setMode ? 'darkTheme' : '']">

    <app-header (mode)="receiveMode($event)"></app-header>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>
```

app.component.css

```
#main-container{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#main-container.darkTheme {
  background-color: #000;
}

#main-container.darkTheme h1{
 color: white;
}

#main-container.darkTheme nav{
 background-color: #fafafa;
}

#main-container.darkTheme .nav-link{
 color: #000;
}

#main-container.darkTheme .nav-link.is-active{
 color: #cb2d67;
}
```

header.component.html

```
<nav>
    <a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="is-active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" class="nav-link" tabindex="1">
        Home
    </a>
    <a routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="is-active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" class="nav-link" tabindex="1">
        About
    </a>

  <button (click)="onChangeToggle()">Toggle Theme</button>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I tried this and it still doesnt work